# Building Web Site looks like Brightstar with Sharepoint

Tags: 2013

I want to make a website looking like the websites in this [link](http://www.topsharepoint.com/category/top-sites?r_sortby=most_rated&r_orderby=desc)

Especially looking like these ones:

http://www.brightstarr.com/

http://www.ferrari.com/

These are my questions:
1.How can I use the webparts in an empty aspx or html file. In SP Designer there is aspx, html and webpart page options to create but I can only use web parts in webpart pages. How can these sites use this web parts in an empty html or aspx pages? What is the settings or coding for this?

2.How can they manage the site,webparts and the settings and permissions of these without a navigation bar which includes Site Settings? are these done on SPDesigner not on browser?

Can you show me a way or send me some links to start to create a website like this? Because when I search on web it all shows a default web site with oslo/seattle theme with navigation bar and master page. Thank you so much. Any idea or helps would be great.

Comment: There are few themes available for free . You can kick start from here . Refer : http://www.topsharepoint.com/avicia-free-sharepoint-online-theme . Download the theme and see how the site looks .Start making changes as you like.

Comment: Thank you so much. It gives me a lot of important point. If I can make it, i will want you to write it an answer. So I can mark it.

Answer (score 1):

You should read about Publishing Websites more on SharePoint.. Read about custom Page Layouts with embedded Web Parts, permissions can be handled at the back-end of SharePoint..

Simply make your website Anonymous Access, only the Owners of the website or site collection administrators can handle the back-end of the website.

You should get some basic training on SharePoint and it will be a good start :)

Comment: Thank you for reply. I will reply again with a certain comment, when I make these work.